# How to find the unique rows in a matrix in matlab, where the order of numbers in row is NOT important?

Tags: matlab, matrix, unique

I have a matrix of following form in matlab:
3 4
4 3
5 6
6 5

I would like to have the rows 1 and 2 to be considered a duplicate, where the elements of the two rows are the same but not in the same order. Similarly rows 3 and 4 should be considered the same. So, given the matrix above, I would like to have the following as the result:
3 4
5 6

I have tried the unique function but it cannot help me for this purpose. 
My actual matrix is quite large, and I don't want to solve the problem with an exhaustive pairwise search, since it is extremely time consuming.
Is there an elegant way of achieving my goal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one way of ding this:

```
X = [3 4
4 3
5 6
6 5];


X = sort(X, 2);
UniqueRows = unique(X, 'rows');

UniqueRows =

     3     4
     5     6
```